# configure netbeans to recognize pkg-config cflags in code completion

Tags: netbeans, pkg-config

is there a way to configure netbeans ide to actually support pkg-config properly? in 'additional options' in C compiler I added `pkg-config --cflags --libs jack sndfile samplerate gtk+-2.0` but i still need to add the directories manually to the include path of the project for the code completion to detect them.

is there a way for netbeans to notice pkg-config commands and to use them to know what to include ?

Answer (score 1):

In the project properties you can set "Additional Options" for both the compiler and the linker (I think you've found this by your question).

However, you must use back quotes around the pkg-config line i.e.

`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` (for the compiler additional options)

`pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` (for the linker)

You might also need to ensure that you are using gnu make as not all variants understand back quotes.